# sort an NSMutableArray that contains NSString objects

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sorting

I am new to objective-c, ios. 
I'm trying to sort in alfabetic order a NSMutableArray called filteredList that contains objects of type NSString.

so if my mutable array contains : [Mary, Bill, John] I would like to have [Bill, Mary, John]

I did the following:

```
[filteredList sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

but I do not see any change. I did read and tried other solutions like compare: instead of localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare but still nothing.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Arrays.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000132-SW5

or 

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSSortDescriptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Your code sorts the mutable array *correctly* to [Bill, John, Mary]. Please show a complete self-contained (non-)working example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated

```
 NSArray *sortedArray =[unSortedArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];//unSortedArray is NSMutableArray
unSortedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:sortedArray];
```

Comment: The array I have is a NSMutableArray. Could you change your code based on the requirements, please?

Comment: unSortedArray is NSMutableArray you just store the sorted value in NSArray (sortedArray).

Comment: for some reasons the tableview displayes the elements in descending mode - instead of  A,B,C I have: C,B,A. Do u have any idea why?

Comment: @justME:how you add values to the array..Show me that

Comment: I m adding elements using [filterList addObject:nsstring]; I just realised that the unSortedArray have the elements in alphabetic order. For some reason the tableView is switching the list upside down. WHY?:)

Comment: @justME:Now you got object in array is alphabetic order but tableview displays in wrong correct?.. [tableView reloadData]; after sort the array

Comment: @justME: Please show how you display data in UITableview with sort method

Comment: well I am using the methods cellForRowAtIndexPath - [self.filterList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] - for each cell in the tableview

Comment: @justME:are you got correct order in Tableview ?. Simply synthesize filterList; instead of synthesize filterList = _filterList;. I m not sure just try like this

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40182/discussion-between-just-me-and-tamilking)

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [filteredList sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(NSString *str1, NSString *str2) {
    return (NSComparisonResult)[str1 compare:str2];
}];
filteredList = [sortedArray mutableCopy];
```

Comment: I've checked if the elements for sortedArray are in corect position. They are, but filteredList is still not popping up ok in my tableview.

Comment: not ok how? not in the right order?

Comment: yes, they are not showing up in the right order in my tableView

Comment: you must sort the array before showing the table view. Otherwise your not using the sorted array

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the below code:-

```
filteredList = (NSMutableArray*)[filteredList sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```